# Javascript - Regex to remove an array of prefixes

Tags: javascript

I need to remove a prefix from a string.  Given an array of known prefixes, I do not know which prefix will exist in a string. One and only one prefix will exist.

```
    function CleanupSupportedItems(data) {
        var prefixes = new Array("TrialLeads", "IPG");

        for (var i = 0; i < prefixes.length - 1; i++) {
            var prefix = new RegExp(/prefixes[i]/g);
            //alert(prefix);
            data = data.replace(prefix, "");
            alert(data);
        }
    }
```

The above code returns undefined on the second iteration.

Given the call

```
CleanupSupportedItems("TrialLeads11");
```

I want a return value of "11".  How can I do it?

Comment: If the resulting values are going to be numbers it would be easier to filter that out....

Comment: @sg3s - Yes return values will always be numeric.  So whatever suggestions you have for this type of improvement are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do without the loop:

```
function CleanupSupportedItems(data) {
    var prefixes = new Array("TrialLeads", "IPG");

    var prefix = new RegExp('^(' + prefixes.join('|') + ')', "g");
    data = data.replace(prefix, "");
    alert(data);
}

CleanupSupportedItems("TrialLeads11");  // alerts 11
CleanupSupportedItems("IPG12");   // alerts 12
```

Here's demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/KkRFp/

Updated to make sure it replaced *only* prefixes and not in between body. Thanks to [minitech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) for pointing it out.

As a suggested improvement, if the input prefixes are expected to have [Regex Special characters](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Regular_expressions_1__Special_characters.html), they would need to be escaped.

Comment: Ooh, I like your use of join to solve the problem I mentioned in my answer :) +1. You should `return data;` too I think.

Comment: @PaulPRO: I just modified the OP's code. He can do whatever since his original issue is fixed now. :)

Comment: -1 Doesn't work for everything - what if someone wanted to remove a prefix `?` or `^` or `$` or `\` or `.` or `(` or `[` or `{`... (you get the idea). http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/KkRFp/1/

Comment: @minitech: That wasn't in the scope of OP's post. You can obviously expand upon this code.

Comment: @minitech Agree with MrChief here, the OP would have mentioned if his prefix could contain special regex characters.

Comment: @Mrchief: I didn't. 2 other people also received a downvote, one for the same reason and one because it didn't work like it should. Besides, "everybody else missed it too, though!!" isn't a valid reason for missing something.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: Also, I just realized, the problems aren't limited to special characters. This will replace a sequence anywhere in the string, not just at the start. Finally, Mrchief, if you would improve your answer instead of stubbornly making excuses, I would withdraw the downvote.

Comment: @minitech the answer is complete within the given scope. if the OP had asked for those, i'd gladly add them. no reason to add more complexity if there isn't a need for it.

Comment: @minitech. i also realized that the problems you mention, are entirely _yours_, not the OP's. e. g. even if he's mentioning _prefix_, you're complaining about global replacement. if you know your working set, then follow KISS principle. i'm sure you'd disagree, but as long as the OP is happy with the solution, i'm too. btw, your solution isn't a silver bullet either. peace out!

Comment: @Mrchief: Strange, I didn't get notified of this comment. Anyways, if you see flaws in *someone*'s answer *feel free to point them out* so that they *can be fixed*. And with the "prefix vs. global replacement thing", I've had it - that's ridiculous. Re-read the question, why don't you. If 'prefix' is specifically mentioned you should replace the prefix. And code should always be bulletproof, with components being *removed*, not *added*, as necessary. What if these prefixes are user input? It's a likely explanation for not knowing what they're going to be.

Comment: @minitech: I guess the `.` confused SO engine. Anyway, I wanted to add this yesterday itself-I don't disagree with the points you raise (prefixing, escaping). Updated my answer so that it replaces _only_ prefixes. The first idea is to present a concise, readable solution that does the job. You can add escaping _if_ you expect such characters in the input, which the OP hasn't mentioned. To make it bulletproof, you need to know _all_ the requirements. I wouldn't downvote someone just because the answer doesn't do something that the OP didn't ask for. You're entitled to your opinion though.

Comment: @Mrchief: Thanks! Downvote removed. It would still be nice if you *mentioned* escaping somewhere though.

Answer (score 2):

You're not creating your RegExp object correctly, do this instead:

```
var prefix = new RegExp('^'+prefixes[i], 'g');
```

After the loop you should also `return data;`

Note that if you ever have a string like 'TrailheadsIPG11', the result will be '11', since you don't exit the loop when a replace is successful, and if your prefixes array contains any of the characters `()[]{}.*+?` or sequences with special meanings in a regex like `\d \w \s` etc. They will be treated as regex, not as characters. If you want to preserver that functionality you can just escape your characters like `\.` instead of `.`.

Comment: Also replaces all instances, not just a single one, regardless of position in string, and fails to escape special characters, or even basic punctuation.

Comment: @minitech That is what it is meant to do :)

Comment: @minitech oh nevermind, I get it now. I added the `^` to make it only match at the start of the string. I don't think punctuation needs to be escaped because the OP's prefixes array doesn't contain any. He would have likely mentioned if the prefixes array could contain any special regex characters

Comment: Okay, -1 removed, but you should still escape the data or at least mention a possible problem. We don't know much about the actual application.

Answer (score 1):

```
RegExp.escape = function(text) {
    return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
};

if(![].map) Array.prototype.map = function(f) { var r = [], i; for(i = 0; i < this.length; i++) r.push(f(this[i])); return r; };

function CleanupSupportedItems(data) {
    var prefixes = ["TrialLeads", "IPG"];

    return data.replace(new RegExp('^(' + prefixes.map(RegExp.escape).join('|') + ')'), ''); // this line changed
}
```

Should do the job. And it does: http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/XZwLU/ (and http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/XZwLU/1/ for a more complicated example)

**EDIT:** I just noticed that you said there would only be one prefix, in the question. That's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

I would build a regex dynamically based on the list of prefixes and replace them with the empty string:

```js
function trimPrefixes(s, ps) {
   return (""+s).replace(new RegExp('^(' + ps.join('|') + ')'), '');
}
// For example...
trimPrefixes("Foo123", ['Foo', 'Bar']); // => "123"
trimPrefixes("Barzip", ['Foo', 'Bar']); // => "zip"
trimPrefixes("I'm ok", ['Foo', 'Bar']); // => "I'm ok"
```

You could also turn that function into a generator if performance is a concern and you've got varying sets of prefixes that will be used repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

If the value is always numeric and at the end of the string:

```
var int = string.match(/[\d]+$/);
if(typeof int != 'undefined')
{
   // There should be a valid (numeric) match in int at this point
}
```

Should capture all the numbers directly on the end of the string without going into complex loops and ridiculous regexes.

For multiple values ofcourse just loop through them with this inside.

Answer (score -1):

You need to be careful when passing variable strings to the regexp object.
Try something like this:

```
function CleanupSupportedItems(data) {
    var prefixes = new Array("TrialLeads", "IPG");

    for (var i = 0; i < prefixes.length - 1; i++) {

        var prefix = new RegExp(prefixes[i], "g");
        //alert(prefix);
        data = data.replace(prefix, "");
    }
              alert(data);
}

CleanupSupportedItems("TrialLeads11");
```

Comment: Again, not escaped, will replace anywhere in the string.